# Grails: Mapping to response codes, impossible to change http status code

Tags: grails

```
"404" (controller: 'error', action: 'pageNotFound')
```

Any changes to response.status inside the pageNotFound action is reverted back to 404 before the response is sent to the client. Is it possible to work around this some way? I would like to be able to change it to 410 when I detect that the resource has been deleted or 301 when it's moved permanently.

Comment: I've also tried to create an 'after' filter, but the status code is reverted after the filter has been executed.

Answer (score 0):

If that's not working try this in your error controller:

```
class ErrorController {

    def notFound = {
        redirect( action: 'gone')
      }

    def gone= {
        response.sendError(410, "Gone")
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually ended up doing it this way, but I'm a little worried that it might confuse Google because it will return a 302 temporary redirect on the original page, and than the 410.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the header yourself manually by response.setHeader()